# Format JSON String without deserialize/serializePretty

Tags: apex

I have a JSON String (as body of a HTTPResponse from a Callout) and I want to format it before storing in a Text(Long) field.

Actual:

```
{"key":"value","key2":[{"key3":"value"}]}
```

Expect:

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": [
    {
      "key3": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

With spaces, CR, ...

A possible way is to `JSON.deserialize()` and then `JSON.serializePretty()` but I do not want to do this way.

Comment: Possible way would be way to go.

Comment: Anything that would indent it correctly would have to parse it to be able to figure out how many braces it has encountered, thus how deeply to indent it. So, I'm not sure that you'll save a whole lot over the round-trip using serializePretty(). You could mess around with the JSONParser class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm), building a string as you go. But there'd have to be a compelling performance reason to need to risk introducing bugs with that.

Comment: Are you on a VF / Controller or batch?

Comment: I would do the JSON.deserialize()/JSON.serializePretty().

Comment: I think the first question is why do you not want to do it that way?

Comment: Serialization/deserialization cost lot in resources and this is only used in a "visual" purpose. It seems to be useless tho

Answer (score 2):

If this json is representation of your apex object or sobject, you can serialize this object with pretty print:

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'test', Phone = '123456789');
JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
generator.writeObject(acc);
System.debug(generator.getAsString());
```

Output:

```
16:45:49.40 (51239589)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account"
  },
  "Name" : "test",
  "Phone" : "123456789"
}
```